# Create views accessible only to certain teams or territory in CRM Online 9.0

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-crm-365-v9

I want to create views that are only available to users that are part of a certain team or territory. I have tried creating a view and add in Edit filter criteria in the image below. I am a part of the team I chose but I do not see records there.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. Views cannot be controlled for visibility by Security role, FLS, only for particular User or Team in any OOB way. Only Dashboard with those views can be made available based on Security role
2. Not sure if your CRM instance records are owned by the Team or user. If the records are owned by individual users, this filter will not work

Answer (score 0):

**NOTE:** *This answer is not a deployable solution, meaning you will have to recreate the views in each environment*

You can try to do this with a "personal" view. Use Advanced Find to create a view with the desired criteria, save it with a meaningful name, and then Share it with the appropriate Team(s)